# Is my reasoning about $ε = iR$ correct, where $ε$ denotes induced emf, $i$ denotes induced current, and $R$ is resistance of loop

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

I came up with the formula, $ε = iR$, where $ε$, $i$ and $R$ denotes induced emf, induced current and resistance of loop respectively. I did the following reasoning to prove this formula, am i right?

[image]

Comment: This is something between "check my work" and a "conceptual question"